# Update jQuery plugin to work with latest version of DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Looking for some assistance in getting this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/ to work with the latest update (v.1.10.x) of jQuery DataTables.  The plugin still drags and drops into a new sort order, however it's throwing an odd jQuery error and is not triggering the AJAX call to update the database.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/Scripts/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
        #ethicsFAQsGrid select {
        width: auto;
    }
    .ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content {
        padding: 10px 30px 10px 15px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ethicsFAQs').dataTable({
            "ajax": "/umbraco/surface/FAQsSurface/getFAQs",
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "order": [[1, 'asc']],
            "pageLength": 10,
            "orderClasses": true,
            stateSave: false,
            "paging": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "destroy": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": 0,
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "data": 1,
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "data": 2,
                    "sortable": false
                },
                {
                    "data": 3,
                    "sortable": false,
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        if ( type === 'display' ) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    className: "dt-body-center"
                },
                {
                    "data": 0,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "class": "dt-center",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"editFAQ(" + data + "); return false;\"><img src=\"/images/Edit_document.png\"/></a>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": 0,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "class": "dt-center",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"deleteOpinion(" + data + "); return false;\"><img src=\"/images/delete.png\"/></a>";
                    }
                }
            ],
            "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
                $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data[3] == "True");
            }
        }).rowReordering({
            sURL: "/umbraco/surface/FAQsSurface/updateFAQsortOrder"
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="ethicsFAQsGrid">
    <table id="ethicsFAQs" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display ca_highlight_row">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>faqID</th>
                <th>sortOrder</th>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>Active?</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
File: jquery-1.10.2.min.js, Line: 21, Column: 15704

Comment: Did you make any changes to the plugin? My guess is you have an extra "#" in one of your jquery expressions, but without seeing the code you've got, it's hard to say.

Comment: No changes.  The author stopped making updates in 2013.  That was before a major upgrade to DataTables.  I was hoping someone could assist with forking and updating the Reordering plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite a problem with 1.10.x, it is the nature of the plugin itself. It was actually the same with dataTables 1.9.x, see proof of concept -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dycnnknz/**

There are two reasons for that :

- rowReordering requires an unique `id` for each row, this is what is causing the *unrecognized expression: #* error.
- It also requires a column dedicated to indexes it is using to calculate internals and the `oState` object, i.e `fromPosition`, `toPosition`, `direction`. The is why the AJAX call fails, the operation is aborted because `iNewPosition` always is `-1` or `NaN`.

Unfortunately those prerequisites are never documented or mentioned *anywhere*.

You can make a table "ready" for rowReordering by adding a `<th></th>` and add row `id`'s and values for the index-column before initialising :

```
var count = $("#example tbody tr").length-1;
$("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).attr('id', 'id'+i);
    $(tr).prepend('<td>'+parseInt(i+1)+'</td>');    
    if (i==count) {
       var table =$("#example")
          .dataTable()    
          .rowReordering({ sURL: "/umbraco/surface/FAQsSurface/updateFAQsortOrder" });
    }     
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/urcz6gL6/**
Now it works without raising errors and goes through to the AJAX call. The demo raises an alert after dragging, this is of course because `/umbraco/surface/FAQsSurface/updateFAQsortOrder` not exists on jsfiddle.com.

Comment: How do you get the zebra stripes to redraw?

Comment: The second demo isn't working, I see the table but it never gets formatted  by dataTable.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko -"_How do you get the zebra stripes to redraw?_" ?? Is it a question in general or related to dataTables?

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko, yes - the second link also produces a dataTable, but some mysterious errors occurs in the console, seems to be related to a jsfiddle update of some kind.

Comment: Looks like I have the DataTables working as expected, even redraws the zebra stripes.  Just seem odd that it keeps the value in the ID column no matter how you drag and drop rows.  I can work with that possibly if I use that as the sort order value and the second column as the actual ID of the row record.

Comment: Ok, got it working for the most part.  I have a couple other issues, but I will start a new thread for those.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko, "_Just seem odd that it keeps the value in the ID column no matter how you drag and drop rows._" - yeah, but it does not keeps them, it reset the values after each row reordering. It is a really primitive plugin approach.  To get it nicer I you could set the row ID column to a width of 0px.

Comment: I can hide the column, that's not an issue.  Just have to set the sort value to column one and my data ID in column 2.  Works like a charm.